# Rep loss for unanswering

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer

It seems that [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47851/pronunciation-of-mcleod/47862#47862) lost rep when the OP decided it was not the correct answer after all.  Fine, except that according to the history, he never accepted it in the first place...
I thought there was a computer run-through every 24 hours or so for minor flaws like this to be ironed out: have I misunderstood?[1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47851/pronunciation-of-mcleod/47862#47862)

Edit to be clear: Rep seems to have gone down for 'unacceptance' without having gone up for acceptance.

Comment: My reputation history shows a -15 on the relevant day, (which is the same day the question was posted, if that helps), and no corresponding +.  I can't be positive that rep is 15 points lower than it should be: I can be sure the change hasn't been properly marked.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at your [reputation tab](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/8019/timlymington?tab=reputation#page_1-view_time) of your profile, you can see the details of both the accept and the unaccept:

[image: rep details]

(In the image, I've used the "by time" detail option.)

Comment: Sorry, this is not in fact the case. On my screen, Nov 9 shows "2 votes" on this question: +25.  I don't pretend to be an expert, but the problem is precisely that "accept" is not shown.

Comment: cut & paste from my viewing of the linked page less than a minute ago agrees with Rebecca's screenshot:  +30  18:38  upvote  Pronunciation of “McLeod”
-15  00:29  **unaccept**  Pronunciation of “McLeod”
25    Nov 9
+15  23:53  **accept**  Pronunciation of “McLeod”
+10  23:47  upvote  Pronunciation of “McLeod”

Comment: @TimLymington you need to select *by time* in order to get the detail you're looking for.  When you're sorting *by post* (which is the default), it groups these situations together by post.

Comment: @TimLymington what screen?  Shows only 10 where?  If you select "by post", it is going to group any positive rep together.  It not being what you expect doesn't mean it is a bug.  I have no idea what you're looking at, and can't help you much without knowing what you're talking about. (:  You can get a list of every single rep point at http://english.stackexchange.com/reputation.

Comment: @TimLymington, the only way to get +25 from two votes is if one of them is an acceptance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all those who took the trouble to comment here.  The bug, whatever it was, has straightened itself out, so I presume it was in my computer.  But if anyone's still interested:  for several days the rep chart, whether by post or by date, showed that post with 4 up votes and an unaccept, (all on the same day, so +25), and nothing else anywhere.